# ansible elastic search install version mismatch failure

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

We are trying to install elastic search and the ansible tasks are failing because for the minor version mismatch.

The Variables we are using are:

```
es_major_version: "5.x"
es_version: "5.5.1"
```

Here is the task def we have

```
name: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch
  yum: name=elasticsearch{% if es_version is defined and es_version != ""  %}-{{ es_version }}{% endif %} state=present update_cache=yes
  when: es_use_repository
  register: redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo
  notify: restart elasticsearch
  until: '"failed" not in redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo'
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

And the Error we are getting is:

```
TASK [elastic.elasticsearch : RedHat - Install Elasticsearch] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: RedHat - Install Elasticsearch (1 retries left).
fatal: [ip-10-0-11-xxx]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 5, "changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["elasticsearch-5.5.1-1.noarch providing elasticsearch-5.5.1-1 is already installed"]}
```

Is there a way we can specify if the minor version mismatch exists don't fail the task.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem with the logic of the retry condition you have specified. if you run the task without the `until` clause, you will see the `failed` attribute exists anyway in the `redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo` variable. I believe you should enhance it by writing it in another way, but looks tricky/time consuming i have to admit

but if your code is already good enough, and you want to fix only the:

> Is there a way we can specify if the minor version mismatch exists don't fail the task.

you can add this `failed_when` instruction:

```
failed_when: redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo.rc != 0
```

because you can see that the rc is 0 in your case.

based on the above, here is a task and its output:

```
  - name: yum install
    yum: name=screen state=present update_cache=yes
    register: redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo
    until: '"failed" not in redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo'
    failed_when: redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo.rc != 0
    retries: 1
    delay: 5


  - name: output
    debug: 
      var: redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo
```

output:

```
TASK [yum install] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: yum install (1 retries left).
ok: [rhel-green]

TASK [output] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel-green] => {
    "redhat_elasticsearch_install_from_repo": {
        "attempts": 1, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": true, 
        "failed_when_result": false, 
        "msg": "", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "results": [
            "screen-4.1.0-0.25.20120314git3c2946.el7.x86_64 providing screen is already installed"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rhel-green                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

the `failed` in the above output comes from the `until` condition, not from the yum task itself. the `failed_when` comes from the `failed_when` and you can see its considered as non-failed.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot ilias-sp. That worked like a charm. Appreciate your help.